# GLSL empty function makes code work

Tags: opengl, glsl

In my fragment shader I have the following function

```
void InitLookUpTables() 
{  
    return;
}
```

Which I call directly in my main function. So when I delete this function call I can't compile this shader anymore, I receive the following error:

> 0(120) : error C5041: cannot locate suitable resource to bind variable
>   "@TMP118". Possibly large array.

Indeed, I have an array of 512 ints in this shader, so it sounds reasonable. I just wonder why is this empty function makes things work.

Comment: Please try to make a minimal shader program that reproduces the problem and show it to us. Otherwise is impossible. Also state what video card you are using.

Comment: And run it through [the validator](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/tools/Reference-Compiler/).